# Java - Eclipse - Take names and numbers from a file, sort alphabetically into a new file, sort numerically into a new file

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, file-io, readfile

I just started learning Java this semester at college and while I can do some of the more basic things and I can work through writing simple programs, I've hit a roadblock in writing this program. I have not learned about trees (seems to be a common fix) and I need help sorting stuff and creating new files.

My file, Players&Score.txt contains the following:

> Bruce 127
>
> Elayna 144
>
> Lisa 153
>
> Marcus 188
>
> Amber 133
>
> Ryan 149
>
> Dorian 099
>
> Joel 175
>
> Jenna 101

So basically I need to sort this list in one file based on name order, then based on the score. My code so far looks like this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Bruce P., November 14, 2013, CSC 131
 * This program uses a file consisting of members of a bowling league. Each line has one name and the average score of the player.
 * The program reads the file and then creates two new files in which one is sorted by alphabetical order of the player's name
 * and the other is sorted in numerical order based on the player's score.
 *
 */

public class MembersAndScores 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File inputFile = new File("Players&Score.txt");
        if (!inputFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File Players&Score.txt was not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
        String line;

        File scoreSort = new File("SortedByName.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(scoreSort);

    }

}
```

I'm probably messing this up or I look really dumb asking for help. I just don't understand this section and how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did your professor say how you're supposed to sort (i.e., are there any particular algorithms you're supposed to use)?

Comment: Not really. We just read the chapter, answered a few questions in class, then he assigned this. We've used insertion sorting before for a program but I couldn't figure out how to make it work really because he wanted us to use a bunch of methods to sort arrays.

Comment: The trick to doing this successfully is to just work on small chunks at a time. The first chunk I'd recommend is to create a function that can sort a list of integers. Talk to your prof. about what type of sort to use and how you can improve your previous insertion sort. Then expand that sorting method to `Comparable` objects (Google that if needed), then build the rest of your program step-by-step.

Comment: @user2947827 @musical_order for beginning java, `selection sort` probably the best solution. You may want to research the step for implementing this sort. It the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This will sort according to the names . I will add the code for scores soon .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Bruce P., November 14, 2013, CSC 131
 * This program uses a file consisting of members of a bowling league. Each line has one name and the average score of the player.
 * The program reads the file and then creates two new files in which one is sorted by alphabetical order of the player's name
 * and the other is sorted in numerical order based on the player's score.
 *
 */

public class MembersAndScores 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        try {
            File inputFile = new File("Players&Score.txt");
            if (!inputFile.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("File Players&Score.txt was not found.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            String line;
            List<String> stl=new LinkedList();
            while(true){
                line=input.readLine();
                if(line!=null&&line.length()>1)
                stl.add(line);
                if(line==null)
                    break;
            }

            data=new String[stl.size()];
            for (int i=0;i<stl.size();i++) {
                data[i]=stl.get(i);
            }

            Arrays.sort(data);
            for (String string : data) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }

            File scoreSort = new File("SortedByName.txt");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(scoreSort);
            for (String string : data) {
                writer.write(string+"\n");
            }

            writer.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MembersAndScores.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

You can get more details of Arrays.sort() [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-tip-how-to-sort-array-in-java-java-util-arrays/)

Comment: This is a well thought-out answer, but in the future please remember that we're here to help people with their existing code, not write new code for them. This is especially important when students ask questions about their assignments.

Comment: I'm sorry for it. Actually I was very busy to integrate the code into the original code and this was my first answer ( In code ) in Stackoverflow . So take it as a beginners mistake :)

Comment: No problem, just remember that for next time.

Comment: Some of this was not useable by me anyway, so I couldn't use some of it and I had to figure out how to work around it and write it to fit my assignment. No harm done.